# php alternatives for standalone web allpications

Tags: windows

I need to develop multi-user web site which also should be able to run locally (on Windows) for a single user. I'd like to use the same code for both sites. Local copy should work without installing any software, source code shouldn't be available, and web browser should be integrated into application. I may use SQLite as local database and  I want to use ExtJS as front-end.

I'm aware of 2 products for PHP that claim to do this, but I'm not sure yet that they will work with the tools I'm interested in (ExtJS and Kohana PHP).

I know that Haskell provides such option, but I don't want to go that far :).

Flex doesn't seem too promising (at least what I remember), as its UI-building capabilities are limited, and I'd like to have online version in HTML, not in Flash.

Are there any other technologies available (.NET, Ruby, Python, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use PHP itself. It's not the neatest solution available, but you can use `php-win.exe` to avoid command-line popping out. You can then use some source obfuscators or byte-code compilers to avoid revealing source code. And AFAIK PHP works without instalation (it can run out of a directory if it has all the required files in it)

As I said, not the neatest solution, but will probably meet your requirements.

Comment: I don't want to be dependent on user's browser. It should be compiled into the application along with the server.

Comment: How about something like this. It would take some integrating but, yeah. http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/